# PHP Upload move_uploaded_file not working

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file, and have it so that duplicate file names will be appended with _0, _1, _2 etc. When a duplicate file is entered I get this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../data/uploads/../data/uploads/Penguins_0.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\staff\upload_form.php on line 29

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\php7150.tmp' to '../data/uploads/../data/uploads/Penguins_0.jpg' in D:\xampp\htdocs\staff\upload_form.php on line 29
Upload failed: Could not move uploaded file. [../data/uploads/Penguins_0.jpg]
```

Can Anyone please help?!

```
$id = "img_" . $_POST['eqId'] . "_" . $_POST['imgId'];
        $file = $_FILES[$id];
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $file["name"]);
        $extension = strtolower(end($temp));
        $dir = "../data/uploads/";
        if(($file["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($file["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($file["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($file["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($file["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($file["type"] == "image/png")
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
            if ($file["error"] > 0){
                echo "There was an error uploading the file. [Code: " . $file["error"] . "]";
            }else{
                $fileName = $file['name'];
                if (file_exists($dir . $file["name"])){
                    $appendCount = 0;
                    while(file_exists($dir . $temp[0] . "_" . $appendCount . "." . $extension)){
                        $appendCount++;
                    }
                    $fileName = ($dir . $temp[0] . "_" . $appendCount . "." . $extension);
                }

                if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $dir . $fileName )){
                    echo "success:" . $file["tmp_name"];
                }else{
                    echo "Upload failed: Could not move uploaded file. [" . $fileName . "]";
                }

            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid file type '" . $extension . "'";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Seconde *answer:***

From your comment , i suggest you before moving file to check if this file fist exists in your upload folder by using **[file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php)**

**First answer:**

As i see , you have problem with the path of your upload folder:

```
../data/uploads/../data/uploads/
```

If not check permissions.

Comment: The strangeness comes from when I upload say "Penguin.jpg" and it works.  But when I upload it again I get that error.

Comment: Hmm I don't know why you deleted your comment anonymous poster who said it was the extra $dir because that was the problem, thank you!. @FaceOfJock, there already is a file_exists check...